# How to delete " from inserted data to MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have got a problem.

Today, I made android application for inserting data into MySQL database.

When I am trying insert **String** type ( example: **name** ), in records show this: **"name"**.

[image: Rows from database]
<----   In database it looks like this image

How to delete **"** from inserted String

This is my PHP script:

```
<?php
require "connect.php";

$firstHash = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZX", 5)), 0, 5);
$secondHash = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWYZX", 5)), 0, 20);

$file_path_URL = "";

$id = "PRD-$firstHash-$secondHash";
$name = $_POST["name"];
$description = $_POST["description"];
$price = $_POST["price"];
$state = $_POST["state"];
$category = $_POST["category"];

$file_path = "uploads/";

$response = array();

if (isset($_FILES["upload_file"]))
{
    $target_file_name = $file_path .basename("$id.png");

    if(file_exists($target_file_name))
    {
        $success = false;
        $message = "Name already exist";
    }
    else
    {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file_name))
        {
            $photoPath = "$file_path_URL$id.png";
            $query = "INSERT INTO `produkty`(`ID`, `Nazwa`, `Opis`, `Cena`, `Stan`, `Zdjecie`, `Kategoria`) VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$description', $price, $state, '$photoPath', '$category')";

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            if(!$result)
            {
                $success = false;
                $message = "Error on insert data";
            }
            else
            {
                $success = true;
                $message = "Add product successfuly";
            }
        }
    else
        {
            $success = false;
            $message = "Error while uploading";
        }

    }


}
else
{
    $success = false;
    $message = "Required Field Missing";
}

$response["success"] = $success;
$response["message"] = $message;

$json = json_encode($response);

echo ($json);
?>
```

Method responsible for get entered data from user in Android:

```
    private void getValues()
{
    Log.v(TAG, "getValues(): init");

    EditText nameET = findViewById(R.id.nameET);
    EditText descriptionET = findViewById(R.id.descriptionET);
    EditText priceET = findViewById(R.id.priceET);
    EditText categoryET = findViewById(R.id.categoryET);
    CheckBox stateCHB = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    String name = nameET.getText().toString();
    String description = descriptionET.getText().toString();
    Float price = Float.valueOf(priceET.getText().toString());
    String category = categoryET.getText().toString();
    boolean state;

    if (stateCHB.isChecked())
    {
        state = true;
    }
    else
    {
        state = false;
    }

    sendDataToServer(name, description, price, state, category, imagePath);

    Log.v(TAG, "getValues(): end");

}
```

I posted it into PHP like String. This is a mistake ?

I am inserting to MySQL database from Android application first time.
Please, help me !

Comment: **use. parameterised. queries.** all your database worries will be over! right now, your code is *begging* hackers to steal all of your data via **SQL injection**

Comment: I am beginner in use MySQL database. I will learn a security of database in future, but thanks for calling your attention for this.

Comment: no. if you tell yourself you learn it in the future, you'll never learn it. also: there is no single reason whatsoever *not* to use parameterised queries. they perform better, are more readable, save you from a ton of potential bugs AND completely protect you from SQL injection attacks. trust me: do it the right way now, or do it the wrong way forever.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't immediately see where the quote is coming from. Perhaps inside 'sendDataToServer' but one solution would be to replace

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

with

```
$name = str_replace( '"', '', $_POST["name"]);
```

in your PHP code to remove the quotes from the POST request when it arrives.